# To show a function is analytic on upper half plane.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis

Let $\mu$ be a complex measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and its Fourier transform is defined by
$$\hat{\mu}(\tau)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i\tau t}\,d\mu(t).$$
Now let us define the function on suitable domain in $\mathbb{C}$ by
$$f(z)=\int_0^\infty e^{i\tau z}\hat{\mu}(\tau)\,d\tau.$$
A textbook claims that the function $f$ is analytic on the upper half plane. How does it follow?

If $\hat{\mu}\in L^1$ then $f$ is well defined on upper half plane and also we can apply Fubini and hence  Morera's theorem to conclude the result. But Fourier transform of a complex measure may not be integrable (right?).

Comment: You are right. $f(z)$ is not even defined in general. Example: Take $\mu=\delta_0$.

Comment: Complex measures are defined with a finite variation, which makes them finite.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy sir, definition of $f(z)$ on the open upper half plane is valid as $\hat{\mu}$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$.